# zfc-rbac module exception

Tags: zend-framework2, zfc-rbac

I integrated the module [`zfcrbac`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac) in my application, apparently there's a problem! when I execute I get the following exception:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend \ ServiceManager \ Exception \ ServiceNotCreatedException' with message 'While Attempting to create zfcrbacguards (alias: ZfcRbac \ Guards) WAS an invalid factory registered for this instance types.' in C: \ wamp \ www \ SSO \ vendor \ ZF2 \ library \ Zend \ ServiceManager \ ServiceManager.php on line 1031
```

I added nothing! just put the module in the vendor directory!

Comment: Have you enabled the ZfcRbac module in application config by adding `ZfcRbac` key to `application.config.php`?

Comment: Yes , i added ZfcRbac in the list of module in application.config.php

Comment: I found the answer , there was a namespaces problem in ini_autoloader.php , i added namespace of zfc-rbac module and it works .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a namespaces problem in ini_autoloader.php , i added namespace of zfc-rbac module and it works